# File upload functionality and message contract usage

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, file-upload

i am new in WCF. once i was searching code for uploading file to web server by wcf. i found a code which uses message contract for file details. i just do not understand why people use message contract. according to that situation the coder can use data contract only instead of message contract....so why they used message contract is not clear.

here is the link of source code for file upload by wcf. just have a look and tell me can we use data contract for file information instead of message contract. give some few good situation when one has to use message contract instead of data contract. thanks

These are the link

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166763/WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP
- http://kjellsj.blogspot.in/2007/02/wcf-streaming-upload-files-over-http.html
- http://stefanoricciardi.com/2009/08/28/file-transfer-with-wcp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference between Data contract and message contract are:

**DataContracts** are used to descibe the data types used by a service.  This enables the types to be described in metadata to enable clients to interop with the service.  DataContracts can be used to describe either parameters or return values.  DataContracts are unnecessary if the service only uses simple types.

**MessageContracts** are used to explicitly describe the soap message format.  It can be used to declare which headers various message elements go.

On Some critical issue, developer will also require control over the SOAP message format. In that case WCF provides Message Contract to customize the message as per requirement.

Very good link is here:
http://izlooite.blogspot.co.il/2010/01/wcf-why-use-messagecontract-when.html
[Can i use datacontracts in WCF for streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574356/can-i-use-datacontracts-in-wcf-for-streaming)